# How to add multiple RoleDefinitions to RoleDefinitionBindingCollection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

Why I can't add multiple role definitions to a RoleDefinitionBindingCollection? Always only the last role is added. Why? Its, a collection of roles, or?

```
 $group = Get-PnPGroup -Identity "MyGroup"
 $assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(Get-PnPContext)
 $assignment.Add((Get-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity "MyRead"))
 $assignment.Add((Get-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity "MyUpdate"))
 $newItem.RoleAssignments.Add($group,$assignment) | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason behind this is **Get-PnPRoleDefinition** command already executing **"ExecuteQuery"** in behind that means it's already sending request to server so only last operation will be sent when you do write "ExecuteQuery".

You can resolve it by using following code:

```
$group = Get-PnPGroup -Identity "MyGroup"
$roleMyRead = Get-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity "MyRead"
$roleMyUpdate = Get-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity "MyUpdate"
$assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(Get-PnPContext)
$assignment.Add($roleMyRead)
$assignment.Add($roleMyUpdate)
$listItem.RoleAssignments.Add($group,$assignment) | Out-Null
$listItem.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes totally sense. But does all PnP PowerShell commands execute "ExecuteQuery" at the end? If no, how you check it or where it is documented?

Comment: More or less most the of PnP PowerShell command does that. and there is no clear documentation about it but you can check source code as it's open source e.g. [GetRoleDefinition](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/blob/dev/src/Commands/Site/GetRoleDefinition.cs).

You can mark this as answer if it did help to you